# Datetime столбец в date-столбец

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть `pd.Series`  `df['Время']`, который имеет формат от года до миллисекунды:

```
>>
0       2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1       2018-12-01 00:11:24.997
2       2018-12-01 00:15:00.000
3       2018-12-01 00:19:42.000
4       2018-12-01 00:29:59.997
5       2018-12-01 00:31:36.997
6       2018-12-01 00:45:00.000
```

Нужно перевести создать столбец, наследующий от него только даты:

```
>>
0       2018-12-01 
1       2018-12-01 
2       2018-12-01 
3       2018-12-01 
4       2018-12-01 
5       2018-12-01 
6       2018-12-01
```

В документации внятного объяснения не нашел. Метод `df['Время'].date()` не работает на `pd.Series`, работает только на конкретном элементе `df['Время'][0].date()`

Comment: @Akina при работе с pandas всё-таки вручную итерироваться по строчкам - плохая практика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае наиболее идиоматическим способом будет использование [`Series.dt.floor()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), т.к. данный метод возвращает `Series` того же типа как и оригинальный `Series`:

```
In [92]: d.dt.floor("1D")
Out[92]:
0   2018-12-01
1   2018-12-01
2   2018-12-01
3   2018-12-01
4   2018-12-01
5   2018-12-01
6   2018-12-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [93]: d.dt.floor("1D").dtype
Out[93]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

`d.dt.date` возвращает `Series` типа `object`, а точнее `Numpy array of Vanilla Python datetime.date`:

```
In [94]: d.dt.date.dtype
Out[94]: dtype('O')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отлично и лаконично

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете обращаться к различным частям даты/времени через [`Series.dt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

```
In [31]: d = pd.Series(['2018-12-01 00:00:00.000', '2018-12-01 00:11:24.997', 
    ...:                '2018-12-01 00:15:00.000', '2018-12-01 00:19:42.000', 
    ...:                '2018-12-01 00:29:59.997', '2018-12-01 00:31:36.997', 
    ...:                '2018-12-01 00:45:00.000'])
    ...: 
    ...:                               

In [32]: d
Out[32]: 
0    2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1    2018-12-01 00:11:24.997
2    2018-12-01 00:15:00.000
3    2018-12-01 00:19:42.000
4    2018-12-01 00:29:59.997
5    2018-12-01 00:31:36.997
6    2018-12-01 00:45:00.000
dtype: object

In [33]: d = pd.to_datetime(d)

In [34]: d
Out[34]: 
0   2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1   2018-12-01 00:11:24.997
2   2018-12-01 00:15:00.000
3   2018-12-01 00:19:42.000
4   2018-12-01 00:29:59.997
5   2018-12-01 00:31:36.997
6   2018-12-01 00:45:00.000
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [35]: d = d.dt.date

In [36]: d
Out[36]: 
0    2018-12-01
1    2018-12-01
2    2018-12-01
3    2018-12-01
4    2018-12-01
5    2018-12-01
6    2018-12-01
dtype: object
```

Comment: Превосходно, благодарю.